# Is this insert possible in function: author meta into a different string?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, author

I need advice. I have been provided with the following code by a plugin developer in order to insert a donation form into the single post template but I need the paypal address to automatically bring in the post author's email address via author meta. Is this possible?

```
function multiple_paypal_accounts( $paypal_args, $payment_data ) {
    $form_id = isset( $payment_data['post_data']['the-form-id'] ) ? $payment_data['post_data']['the-form-id'] : '';
    if('3830' === $form_id ) {
        // Here I want to customize the email address to show the post author's paypal email address
        $paypal_args['business'] = 'THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PULL IN THE PAYPAL ADDRESS FROM AUTHOR META DATA';
    }
    // Always return the paypal args.
    return $paypal_args;
}
add_filter( 'the_form_paypal_redirect_args', 'multiple_paypal_accounts', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: my guess would be: global $post;
$author_id=$post->post_author; $author_email =  get_the_author_meta('email', $author_id );

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question, forms accept GET and POST parameters and by the looks of it the variable $payment_data is used like the following: `$payment_data['post_data'][?]`. This appears to potentially hold this information. `$payment_data['post_data']['email']` would be a bold guess but may not be correct.

If it were correct you can left-asign like so: `$paypal_args['business'] = $payment_data['post_data']['email'];`

If not you can perform a var_dump() of `$payment_data['post_data']` to find out what the contents this variable might hold. More on this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php